# Pygame window sizing when converted to exe with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pygame, pyinstaller

So I converted my game to an exe with pyinstaller but when i run it the scale is different and the resolution is slightly fizzy. I'm not sure what other detail to provide here but I'm using pygame-ce 2.3.0 (SDL 2.26.4, Python 3.11.3), now also tested on pygame-ce 2.4.0.dev2 (SDL 2.26.5, Python 3.11.3) still same results. pyinstaller command used (from the terminal in pycharm): pyinstaller --onefile --windowed main.py

code recreation:

constants.py:

```
import pygame

scale = 1
x_offset = 0
tile_size = 16

sw, sh = 240, 160
screen = pygame.Surface((sw, sh))
if scale == 'f':
    window = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
    scale = window.get_height() / sh
    x_offset = (window.get_width() - scale * tile_size * 15) / 2
else:
    window = pygame.display.set_mode((sw * scale, sh * scale))
```

main.py:

```
import pygame
import constants as c

running = True
while running:
    c.screen.blit(pygame.image.load("res/test.png"), (0, 0))  # test to show screen resolution, use your own image of the correct screen dimensions to see for yourself.
    c.window.blit(pygame.transform.scale_by(c.screen, c.scale), (0 + c.x_offset, 0))
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

[I have run the exe (on the left) and the py file with pycharm (on the right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/it9ra.png)

I am unsure why the exe is scaled and fuzzy, I was expecting them to be the same.

Comment: In your code are you explicitly defining the size of the window in pixels? Please post the part of your code where you define the window size

Comment: Might be related to scaled window resolution ([e.g.](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/1984) or [2](https://github.com/pygame-community/pygame-ce/issues/2338)). Have you tried updating your libraries to their respective latest releases? Otherwise, please [edit] your question to include a [mre].

Comment: I have updated pygame-ce to 2.4.0 still no result. And i dont think your examples are of relivance because there is no scaleing anywhere of the window or actual screen. the pygame surface screen is blited to the window at the scale. I have incorperated more code so you should have a replicatible result, i have not tested it though so if it acts as intended I'll try adding more code that could be the issue.